# How to call a javascript function when iframe finished loading?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Could any one tell me how I can detect if an iframe has finished loading so I can call a javascript function and alert the user that iframe finished loading and do some other process inside the javascript function? (Note my iframe is my own site) Can I fire callback from within the iframe as I can have control over it? if yes how ?

```
<iframe id ='myframe' src='http://www.example.com/doit.php'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

try this

```
<iframe id ='myframe' src='http://www.mysite.com/doit.php' onload="onLoadHandler();"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoadHandler() {
    alert('loaded');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 14):

If using jQuery, handle it just like anything loading:

```
$('#myframe').on('load', function() {
    // Handler for "load" called.
});
```

Obsolete answer:

```
$('#myframe').load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

Comment: Calling .load is now deprecated, use .on('load', function() {}) instead

Comment: Only add a note: It is deprecated since version 3.x, but you can use it yet if you are in older versions

Answer (score 3):

With just plain javascript

```
document.querySelector('#myframe').addEventListener("load", ev => {
    // your stuff
})
```